# Is it possible to control network traffic per url with TC?

Tags: networking, web-server, tc

I need to slowdown a specific call to a Web-service but only for a specific url on the same host:
    I have my program configured to call (GET)

```
    URL1 = http://my-remote-system.domain.net:567/product-web-services/fastmethod?some=1&query=2&params=3

    URL2 = http://my-remote-system.domain.net:567/product-web-services/slowmethod?some=4&query=5&params=6
```

I want to put a delay when my program call the second url and I know `tc` is quite powerful but cannot find a proper example for such a case.
    The server I call is the same URL, just the path and query params are different.

Another alternative with TC would be to make normal (fast) calls on the specific IP and a slow one every 5th call only on this specific IP.

I know I can do it by using a proxy but that would change my program configuration and I would prefer to control the network directly (if possible).

I mention `tc` but if another tool working on Linux is easy to install and configure, that could be an alternative.

Comment: Why? I dont see how making a connection linger for longer than it needs to serves you any advantage.

Comment: @MatthewIfe it is just for integration testing with some delay for a specific url but not for the others. Test to be sure that some error handling is correctly developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TC operates at a IP level, so it is unable to distinguish between those two urls. Maybe look at a proxy like http://www.deelay.me/.